# Help on build using g++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, g++, cygwin

There is a small project C++ (it has win32 code) that I need to build. It already has its Makefile. I was told to use MinGW. I have never used it before. I downloaded and installed the latest MinGW installer.

Then, I opened the MinGW shell and did `make`. The exe file was created. But when I try to run it I get `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` is missing! Why do I get this error? Shouldn't the exe be self-contained and run anywhere?

**UPDATE**
Here's more information, from the Makefile:

```
CC = g++ 
CCOPTIONS=-DWINDOWS -DFORCEINLINE -DMINGW -DSRTP_SUPPORT -D__EXPORT= -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNOMVS    
setup.exe: setup.o common.o 
    $(CC) -ggdb -g -O0 -o $@ setup.o common.o  -mno-cygwin -mwindows -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -lmapi32 -lVfw32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not the exe should be self-contained depends on how you built it. We need to see the commands that were executed, or post the makefile. But that DLL does not seem to be part of the current version of MinGW. Also, please clarify if you are actually doing this under cygwin, or if you added the tag by mistake.

**Edit:** A bit of googling seems like it has to do with the horrible "official" MinGW installation. Remove it, and download the Twilight Dragon build from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net and then rebuild completely.  The "official" build is cr*p anyway - I don't know why anyone uses it.

Comment: Updated post.I downloaded and installed MinGW from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ (added msys support).I tagged as cygwin because there was no other tag with linux-like for windows

Comment: Thank you I will try it.Can it compile code of win32 also?After you original post though, the option `-mno-cygwin` in makefile make me causious.Could that cause any issue?

Comment: @user Don't know - it's not one I ever use myself. The TDM distribution is a  reworked version of MinGW, it can do everything MinGW can _ I use it for all my C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is a stand alone application with MinGW, you should add `-static` to the linking options.

On a side note, if you're making a Win32 application, add the `-mwindows` option to the C++ compiler so it doesn't open a console together with your main window.

Comment: He has -mwindows. And whether -static is needed depends on what he is linking with.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: You're right, I missed the `-mwindows` on his CCOPTIONS. I would give `-static` a try though, because I have a recent version of MinGW and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is part of it.